# The resource cannot be found. RouteConfig in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

please see details :

RouteConfig class :

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Templates",
                url: "templates/{controller}/{template}",
                defaults: new { action = "Template" }
                );
        }
    }
```

TeamsController :

```
  public class TeamsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Template(string template)
        {
            switch (template.ToLower())
            {
                case "list":
                    return PartialView(Url.Content("~/Views/Teams/List.cshtml"));
                case "add":
                    return PartialView(Url.Content("~/Views/Teams/Add.cshtml"));
                case "delete":
                    return PartialView(Url.Content("~/Views/Teams/Delete.cshtml"));
                case "edit":
                    return PartialView(Url.Content("~/Views/Teams/Edit.cshtml"));
                case "detail":
                    return PartialView(Url.Content("~/Views/Teams/Detail.cshtml"));
                default:
                    throw new Exception("template not known");
            }
        }
    }
```

url request : `http://localhost:1533/templates/teams/add`

**error** : Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Why this error occurs ?

Comment: Move the `Default` route to after the `Templates` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reordering your routes in `RouteConfig.cs` file as shown:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Templates",                          //move custom routes above default routes
            url: "templates/{controller}/{template}",
            defaults: new { action = "Template" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
}
```

I m providing a small explanation of your problem here so that you can easily understand,look when we run our mvc application then a routing table is generated in global.asax file where you register your routes so as per your routing the default routes will be registered first and default route will be above in preference as compared to your custom routes so its always adviced that put custom routes above default routes as shown in my answer.

A good article on common mistakes in MVC routing is [here](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/09/three-common-aspnet-mvc-url-routing-issues/) read this.